# How to validate 5 text boxes in behind code with efficient code? this what I was trying but it gives me error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My code is more complex than that but to keep it simple just posted 5 button and when I click a button I want to do some logic to validate each text box. But doing it in a loop by just changing the ID as shown on code behind. Any help would be appreciated

.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeID1" runat="server" Width="95px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeID2" runat="server" Width="95px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeID3" runat="server" Width="95px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeID4" runat="server" Width="95px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeID5" runat="server" Width="95px"></asp:TextBox>
```

.aspx.vb

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Validate emptext

    Dim b As Integer = 1
    Dim employeeid As TextBox

    Do While b < 6
        employeeid.ID = "EmployeeID" & "1" '(b.ToString())
        Dim str As String = employeeid.Text
        b = b + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the validation logic the same for all the controls or does each control have its own validation logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of your TextBox and loop over that array elements

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim txts = {txtEmployeeID1, txtEmployeeID2, txtEmployeeID3, txtEmployeeID4, txtEmployeeID5}

    ForEach t in txts
        Dim str As String = t.Text
        .... do you checks here ...
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate method that handles the validation and call it from the button click event.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.ValidateEmployeeID(Me.txtEmployeeID1)
    Me.ValidateEmployeeID(Me.txtEmployeeID2)
    Me.ValidateEmployeeID(Me.txtEmployeeID3)
    Me.ValidateEmployeeID(Me.txtEmployeeID4)
    Me.ValidateEmployeeID(Me.txtEmployeeID5)
End Sub

Private Sub ValidateEmployeeID(textBox As TextBox)
    ' common logic here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

here is some code i use on the regular. you will need to modify slightly based on your needs, but this comes in handy very often. written in VB.NET for ASP.NET

first use this function to get a list of textboxes inside of any control.

```
''' <summary>
''' get a list of all textboxes nested under ctrlParent and its children.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="ctrlParent"></param>
''' <param name="getReadOnlyTxts">
''' If this is set to false then textboxes with the class "txtReadOnly" will be ignored.
''' Otherwise all textboxes can be returned in this funciton
''' </param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks>
''' this is a recursive function that calls itself.
''' </remarks>

Public Function GetList_Textboxes(ByVal ctrlParent As Control, ByRef getReadOnlyTxts As Boolean) As List(Of TextBox)

    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim txt As TextBox
    Dim lstTxtbox As New List(Of TextBox)

    For Each ctrl In ctrlParent.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then

            txt = TryCast(ctrl, TextBox)

            If getReadOnlyTxts Then
                'get read only texts is true, so add the textbox without checking
                lstTxtbox.Add(txt)

            Else
                'get read only textboxes is not true, so check to make sure
                'this textbox is not readonly before adding
                If Not InStr(txt.CssClass, "txtReadOnly") > 0 Then
                    lstTxtbox.Add(txt)

                End If

            End If

        End If

        ' If the control has children, recursively call this function
        If ctrl.HasControls Then
            lstTxtbox.AddRange(GetList_Textboxes(ctrl, getReadOnlyTxts))
        End If
    Next

    Return lstTxtbox

End Function
```

then pass the resulting list of that function to this one:

```
''' <summary>
''' send a list of textboxes to validate
''' if the control is empty then its backcolor will be changed and valid will be set to false
''' </summary>
''' <param name="lstTxtboxs"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>

Public Function Validate_Textboxes(ByRef lstTxtboxs As List(Of TextBox)) As Boolean

    Dim valid As Boolean = True

    For Each txtbox As TextBox In lstTxtboxs

        If Trim(txtbox.Text) = "" Then
            txtbox.BackColor = _ctrlColorError
            valid = False
        Else
            txtbox.BackColor = _ctrlColorNormal
        End If

    Next

    Return valid

End Function
```

You will only have to write those 2 above methods once, and make them public in a class file or something. From then on you will only have to do the below to validate if your textboxes are empty:

```
Dim lstRequiredTxtbxs As New List(Of TextBox)
lstRequiredTxtbxs = GetList_Textboxes(ID_ofControlToLookForTextboxesUnder, False)
Dim areTextboxesValid as Boolean = Validate_Textboxes(lstRequiredTxtbxs)
```

Answer (score 0):

e.g 1:

```
Dim emptyTextBoxes =
    From txt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    Where txt.Text.Length = 0
    Select txt.Name
If emptyTextBoxes.Any Then
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Please fill following textboxes: {0}",
                    String.Join(",", emptyTextBoxes)))
End If
```

e.g 2:

```
void ProcessTextBoxes(Control parent) {
   foreach(Control child in parent.Controls) {
      TextBox textBox = child as TextBox;
      if (textBox != null) // type match
          ProcessTextBox(textBox); //define some method to work with individual text box
      else
          ProcessTextBoxes(parent); //recursive
   } //loop
}
```

Comment: i don't think this is asp.net friendly code, which is what the OP was asking for...